# iCloud Keychain required for kSecAttrSynchronizable?

Tags: ios, icloud, keychain

I have implemented synchronised keychain storage in my App with the SecKeychain API using kSecAttrSynchronizable. Am I correct in thinking that iCloud keychain must be enabled (iOS settings > iCloud > iCloud keychain) for this to work?

If so, is there any way to tell if this is enabled?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Don't think there is a public API to check the status of iCloud Keychain

Answer (score 0):

The `kSecAttrSynchronizable` attribute is used by your app to tell keychain if it is desired behavior that this keychain entry is synced to other Apple devices of that user or not.

Why would you desire an item **not** to be synced? E.g. the user doesn't want it to be synced as he wants to use a different password on his iPhone and on his iPad; so you may like to offer a pref and let the user chose if he desires syncing this password. Or syncing this password is simply not meaningful, e.g. it is a password that is used to encrypt local data of your application, local data that will only be present on the current device and thus this password is of no use to other devices, they lack the data for decryption.

However, your app can only express the wish for your item to be synced, whether syncing takes place at all is up to the user. The user decides if he wants password syncing at all, after all password syncing requires the passwords to be stored on Apple's servers. They are stored encrypted and not even Apple themselves have access to the password data, yet some users still don't have a good feeling having when that kind of information lying around on public servers on the Internet. So unless a user enables syncing, no passwords are synced.

Why would you need to know if the user has enabled it? To tell the user that passwords are not synced unless he enables syncing of passwords? Sounds a bit like telling the user that the room is dark, unless he turns on the light. If it is not on, the user may have chosen so on purpose, you cannot know if he did, can you? If you offer an option for password synchronization in the app prefs and the user enables is, just show an info text below that this feature requires iCloud keychain syncing to be enabled or else will have no effect.

Other than that, if you don't offer such an option, it should still be pretty obvious to all users that when your app promises "Now supporting iCloud Keychain Synchronization" that this feature will only work if "iCloud Keychain Synchronization" is enabled, don't you think? So to my best knowledge, there is no API that will directly tell you. One may detect in indirectly through other means but I don't recommend such kind of hacks, they are very fragile and sooner or later break with an update.

Comment: I was not storing a password but other secret data which allows the App to connect to specific devices. If iCloud Keychain is not enabled the user would not understand why it is not syncing the data between the devices. I don't think most users would understand what 'iCloud keychain' is and why it has relevance to that, especially if I can't communicate that clearly when it is off.